# Using AppleScript to Execute API GraphQL Mutations

Tags: graphql, applescript

I am trying to use AppleScript to control an application called Soundtrack (similar to Spotify, but for business accounts).

Normally, I control Spotify through AppleScripts that are activated by MIDI notes using an application called ProPresenter (a type of presentation software).

I cannot get Soundtrack to respond to any AppleScript (other than activating), so I assume that is because the app developer hasn't developed an AppleScript dictionary for Soundtrack?

I do have access to the Soundtrack API and have managed to use Postman to generate some scripts to control the application.

I'm trying to implement the above referenced scripts into some AppleScripts that can be triggered by ProPresenter.

My background is not in scripting; Google has helped a lot in the past, and this time I used ChatGPT to help out in figuring a solution, but I'm hitting a brick wall. I have an AppleScript that looks like it should work, but I need some help to figure out if I'm doing something wrong, or trying to do something that is not possible.

The current AppleScript that I am trying to use is as follows:

```
-- Replace "your_sound_zone_id_here" with your actual Sound Zone ID
set soundZoneId to "your_sound_zone_id_here"

-- Replace "your_api_key_here" with your actual API Key
set apiKey to "your_api_key_here"

-- GraphQL query to retrieve sound zone information with variables
set soundZoneQuery to "mutation SetVolume($soundZoneId: ID!) {
  setVolume(input: { soundZone: $soundZoneId, volume: 8 }) {
    soundZone
    status
    volume
  }
}"

-- Build the GraphQL request
set graphQLRequest to "json='{\"query\": \"" & soundZoneQuery & "\"}'"

-- Execute the GraphQL request using osascript with Basic Auth
do shell script "curl -X POST 'https://api.soundtrackyourbrand.com/v2' -H 'Authorization: Basic " & apiKey & "' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<< " & quoted form of graphQLRequest
```

Using the same GraphQL query/mutation in Postman yields the expected results of setting the application volume to 8. Using this AppleScript, however, yields no results, just an empty set of quotes and nothing changed in the Soundtrack application.

If I'm trying to do something not possible or allowed by the Soundtrack API, my other option is to have Postman running in the background and create an AppleScript to control that, but I haven't gotten there quite yet.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be doing the right thing, it just seems that your applescript is not actually executing the `curl` command. Either it's not running at all or the graphql query/mutations are incorrect. I recommend you try running the exact same curl commands from a terminal on your mac that way you might get better debugging info. Postman isn't doing anything magical on the network that you can't do from a terminal.

Comment: @MichelFloyd thank you. The `curl` command worked as expected in Terminal. I'm not sure why it isn't working in Script Editor. I ended up just setting up the curl command to run in Terminal from within the AppleScript.

Comment: It's probably going to be some nit with how the GraphQL request is quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly quote and escape soundZoneId variable in the query definition.

```js
-- Replace "your_sound_zone_id_here" with your actual Sound Zone ID
set soundZoneId to "your_sound_zone_id_here"

-- Replace "your_api_key_here" with your actual API Key
set apiKey to "your_api_key_here"

-- GraphQL query to retrieve sound zone information with variables
set soundZoneQuery to "mutation SetVolume($soundZoneId: ID = \\\"" & $soundZoneId & "\\\") {
  setVolume(input: { soundZone: $soundZoneId, volume: 8 }) {
    soundZone
    status
    volume
  }
}"

-- Build the GraphQL request
set graphQLRequest to "{\"query\": \"" & soundZoneQuery & "\"}"

-- Execute the GraphQL request using osascript with Basic Auth
do shell script "curl -X POST 'https://api.soundtrackyourbrand.com/v2' -H 'Authorization: Basic " & apiKey & "' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d @- <<< " & quoted form of graphQLRequest
```